# "Dynamic" JSON Decoding with Circe

Tags: json, scala, circe

Consider this JSON:

```
{
  "myDocument": {
    "static_key": "value",
    "dynamic_key": "value",
    "static_key2": "value2",
    "dynamic_key2": {
      "dynamic_key3": "value3"
    }
  }
}
```

The JSON documents that I'm going to process have some static keys (fields that I know that are going to be present always) but has some others that could be or not be present, with names unbeknownst in advance for mapping them to some `case class`.

I have the absolute path to the field in a String (retrieved from a configuration stored in a Database) with the following structure:

`"myDocument.dynamic_key2.dynamic_key3"`

I know that I need to have an ADT for mapping back and forth, so I came to this:

```
sealed trait Data

final case class StringTuple(key: String, value: String) extends Data

object StringTuple {

  implicit val encoder: Encoder[StringTuple] = deriveEncoder[StringTuple]
  implicit val decoder: Decoder[StringTuple] = deriveDecoder[StringTuple]
}

final case class NumericTuple(key: String, value: Double) extends Data

object NumericTuple {

  implicit val encoder: Encoder[NumericTuple] = deriveEncoder[NumericTuple]
  implicit val decoder: Decoder[NumericTuple] = deriveDecoder[NumericTuple]
}

final case class DateTuple(key: String, value: OffsetDateTime) extends Data

object DateTuple {

  implicit val encoder: Encoder[DateTuple] = deriveEncoder[DateTuple]
  implicit val decoder: Decoder[DateTuple] = deriveDecoder[DateTuple]
}

final case class TransformedJson(data: Data*)

object TransformedJson {

  def apply(data: Data*): TransformedJson = new TransformedJson(data: _*)

  implicit val encoder: Encoder[TransformedJson] = deriveEncoder[TransformedJson]
  implicit val decoder: Decoder[TransformedJson] = deriveDecoder[TransformedJson]
}
```

Based on this [discussion](https://github.com/circe/circe/issues/216#issuecomment-191730128), it makes no sense to use `Map[String, Any]` with circe, so I divided the three possible key-value cases that I will encounter when parsing individual fields:

- A numeric field, that I'm going to parse as `Double`.
- A String field parsed as is (`String`).
- A date field parsed as `OffsetDateTime`.

For that reason, I've created three case classes that model these combinations (`NumericTuple`, `StringTuple` and `DateTuple`) and my idea is to produce an output JSON like this:

```
{
  "dynamic_key": "extractedValue",
  "dynamic_key3": "extractedValue3",
  ...
}
```

("Plain", with no nesting at all).

My idea is to create a list of `Data` objects to achieve this and I have something like this:

```
def extractValue(confElement: Conf, json: String) = {
    val cursor: HCursor = parse(json).getOrElse(Json.Null).hcursor
    val decodeDynamicParam = Decoder[NumericTuple].prepare(
      /*
          Here I think (not sure) that I can extract the value with the decoder,
          but, how can I extract the key name and set it, alongside with the extracted
          value?
       */
      _.downField(confElement.path)
    )
  }
```

**Some considerations:**

1. [Based on Travis' response to this question](https://github.com/circe/circe/issues/216#issuecomment-191730128) I'm trying to model the JSON as closely as possible for working with circe. That's why I tried with the *tuples* model.
2. [Based (again) on Travis's response to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42304877/478030) is that I'm trying with `Decode.prepare(...)` method. And here comes my question...

**Question:** How do I extract the specific key name of the current cursor position and map it to the `Tuple`?
I need only the current key, not all the key set that `.keys` method of `ACursor` returns. With that key, I want to map manually the Tuple with the current key name and the extracted value.

For summing it up, my need is to transform a structure that has some unknown keys (name and position), extract their values based on the absolute-dot-separated path that I have and lift both the key name and the value name to a case class that I suffixed as `Tuple`.

Can you shed some light about this?

Thanks

Comment: You have to split the field into a List and recursively call `downField`.